# Error: anonymous class is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, listactivity

Please, I am getting an error in the method below whenever I try to build my android project.

Method :

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                if (e == null) {
                    objects = removeCurrentUser(objects);
                    mUsers = objects.toArray(new ParseObject[0]);

                    // Get user relations
                    ParseRelation userRelations = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getRelation("UserRelation");
                    userRelations.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(SelectUsersActivity.this, mUsers, new ArrayList<ParseObject>(results));
                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                            else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught!", e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                    Toast.makeText(SelectUsersActivity.this, "Sorry, there was an error getting users!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }//
         );
```

Errors :

> Error:(46, 45) error:  is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method done(List,ParseException) in FindCallback
>
> Error:(48, 16) error: name clash:
>   done(List,ParseException) in  and
>   done(List,ParseException) in FindCallback have the same erasure,
>   yet neither overrides the other where T is a type-variable: T extends
>   ParseObject declared in interface FindCallback

Here is [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBAn0.jpg)

Comment: is your done method is declared as abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't parameterized your anonymous [`FindCallback`](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/FindCallback.html) subclass, so your `done` signature doesn't match the `FindCallback#done` signature because the `done` signature in the un-parameterized version is `done(List<Object>results, ParseException e)`.

To fix it, parameterize it:

```
userRelations.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
// Add ---------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```